# Difference between ob_clean and ob_flush?

Tags: php, output-buffering

What's the difference between `ob_clean()` and `ob_flush()`?

Also what's the difference between `ob_end_clean()` and `ob_end_flush()`? I know `ob_get_clean()` and `ob_get_flush()` both get the contents and end output buffering.

Comment: See the manual pages on [`ob_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_clean) and [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/ob_flush) and [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) and [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/ob_end_flush) or explain which specific aspect needs elaboration.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: I've been studying them, it doesn't look like there is a difference.  Even in the examples.

Comment: @AlexV I've updated my answer... but basically these functions write directly to the output-buffer (just like `print` or `echo`), therefore you will see no difference in the function signatures.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

the `*_clean` variants just empty the buffer, whereas `*_flush` functions print what is in the buffer  (send the contents to the output buffer).

#### Example:

```
ob_start();
print "foo";      // This never prints because ob_end_clean just empties
ob_end_clean();   //    the buffer and never prints or returns anything.

ob_start();
print "bar";      // This IS printed, but just not right here.
ob_end_flush();   // It's printed here, because ob_end_flush "prints" what's in
                  // the buffer, rather than returning it
                  //     (unlike the ob_get_* functions)
```

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is
`*_clean()` discards changes and `*_flush()` outputs to the browser.

**Usage of `ob_end_clean()`**

it is mostly used when you want to have a chunk of html and do not want to output to the browser right away but may be used in future.

Eg.

```
ob_start()
echo "<some html chunk>";
$htmlIntermediateData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

{{some more business logic}}

ob_start();
echo "<some html chunk>";
$someMoreCode = ob_get_content();
ob_end_clean();

renderTogether($htmlIntermediateCode, $someMoreCode);
```

**where as `ob_end_flush()` will render twice, once for each.**